# Cannot makemigrations on Django Settings already configured error

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm a new django developer and I recently started a project, and am trying to get the database up and running.

For background: we are using a mysql database for storage, and the settings are configured for it. Using an Unbuntu DO server. I have also been using the virtual environment to run the commands below.

When we initially created the project we ran the makemigrations command, which populated the database with django tables, but not the Models, as we had not made any Models yet. I've now uploaded the Model code, however I could not make any new migrations, I got the error RuntimeError("Settings already configured").

According to this tutorial which I was following (https://www.geekinsta.com/how-to-customize-django-user-model/) some errors are normal and required me to delete and recreate the mysql database (which I did, it has the same name), and clear past migrations (the app/migrations/**pycache** is now empty). However I'm still experiencing the same error ("Settings already configured").

How can I fix this? I need to successfully run the makemigrations and migrate commands to populate the database. The new database and pycache are empty after I attempted the commands again. Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have written? It looks like you are trying to configure django project somewhere and it is already configured somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Sadan. Thanks for helping out. I fixed the error! It turns out I had called settings.configure() in the top of my models file with the import statements when I had been trying to solve a different problem earlier. I'll be marking this as resolved.